# Combine DirectShow with OpenCV

Tags: c#, opencv, directshow, emgucv

I am getting video feed using DirectShow in my C# Web Form. Now i want to process the frames using OpenCV. (EmguCV Wrapper)

1) How would i collect frames from DirectShow feed.

2) Is there a Way to combine DS & OpenCV.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to write your own direct show filter?

Comment: A Little Bit.. I found a DirectX code for my task (i.e. Extracting Frames).. What is the difference between the two approaches.. DirectShow vs DirectX

Comment: Afaik DirectX uses DirectShow for 2D rendering so there should be no difference but I'm quite new to DirectShow  too so I might be wrong there.

Comment: You should be able to extract frames from a DirectShow feed. This might help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1353/Extracting-bitmaps-from-movies-using-DirectShow . You should be able to manipulate the pixel data from a captured frame using OpenCV (depending on the image format your frame is using you might need to tweak things a little bit). Here is a skeleton for OpenGL+OpenCV application, which might give you some pointers what to do next: http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~holl/CS290I/opengl_cv.cpp I've used it myself and it's working.

Comment: @Micka, yes, as far as I know DirectShow is for 2D rendering only. But a 3D can easily be converted to 2D. After all this is what's actually happening when a 3D object is displayed on our 2D displays. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get iplImage or Mat from directshow to opencv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477314/get-iplimage-or-mat-from-directshow-to-opencv)

Comment: @user3752779 did you end up doing it?

Answer (score 2):

From your description, using a [`SampleGrabber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377544(v=vs.85).aspx) filter should suffice. The SampleGrabber will allow you to grab the individual frames, after which you can store and process it as you need.

Example usage can be found [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407288(v=vs.85).aspx)